# Solution setup multi Target Windows Phone Apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, multitargeting

I need to write a windows phone app that is compatible with both WP 7.5/7.8 and WP 8.

Now how do I have to setup my solution to target both platform?

I already create a class library for accessing data.

EDIT

How do i create a Windows Phone Projec that contains a version of the app compatible with WP7.X and another version compatible only with WP8 but having a single app on the store?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your solution and target the WP 7.1

Your app will be compatible with WP 7.5/7.8 and WP8.

Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13725010/1565574