# Build applications for Windows phone 8 using VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

Is there a way to build Windows phone 8 applications using Windows 7 and VS 2010 ? Or is mandatory yo have installed Windows 8 and VS 2012, if so is there possible a conversion from application build using VS 2010 on Windows 7 to the one required by Windows 8 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want this, anyways?

Comment: I have installed and license only for windows 7 and vs 2010.

Comment: Just use Express, really. (not sure if you can publish a store app from Express)

Comment: It seems that VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8 cannot be installed on Windows 7.

Comment: Still, Win8 isn't that expensive.

Comment: I agree, but still installing it will change a lot of things on the PC.

Comment: No it won't... the upgrade costed me two prgroams.

Comment: Yeah, but also the way of working will be changed, the fact that the "close window" button is gone really freaks me out since i was using it intensively.

Comment: @MirceaLucian the close window button? I've been using windows 8 for ages, and this is news to me; the *start* button is gone, sure - although apparently that'll be back in 8.1

Comment: Close Window button's still there: the start menu's gone, but if you really, really miss it (you won't) use ClassicShell or something like  that.

Comment: I mean the "X" button from top right corner of each application's window. Which is a MS legacy from Windows 95 :), along with "Minimize" and "Resize / Maximize" window buttons :).

Comment: @MirceaLucian yeah, that's still there

Comment: Ok. may be i am a Windows 8 novice, but still for instance in Internet Explorer from Windows 8 i just could not see it.

Comment: Anyway i am going to sleep now... i will look harder to seek that "X" button :) ,when i will be using again the Windows 8. Thank you again for information and comments !

Comment: @MirceaLucian oh, you mean in metro, er... Windows Store mode? yeah, but most of the time you **aren't using that**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need windows 8. No, it won't work on Visual Studio 2010 - but that also doesn't mean that you *need* Visual Studio 2012 - you can use [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone)

Also keep in mind that the emulator for this uses Hyper-V, so you'll need a machine capable of running in hypervisor mode. Full system requirements are listed on the linked page (x64, win 8 pro, hyper-v, SLAT, etc)

Comment: (as in a machine that has SLAT)

Comment: actually, it's the Windows Phone SDK that is not installable on anything besides Windows 8 (as of now) ;-)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance yes, I was just in the process of appending the basic system requirements, but the linked page shows them

Comment: @thriqon which both Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone and the Windows Phone support in Visual Studio 2012 *make use of*, no?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you somehow know, if i will build an application for Windows Phone 7.1 or something like that, it will run on Windows Phone 8 ? Is there such a compatibility ?

Comment: @MirceaLucian apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724852/are-windows-phone-7-apps-compatible-on-windows-phone-8-devices - however, you will be limited to the 7.x feature set

Comment: @Marc Gravell, thank you ! it seems that there is a "hard way" for that :), this was the "main" info which i seek it.