# Deploy windows phone 7.1 app on windows phone 8 device

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, zune

I want to test an app which is build on 7.1 sdk and want to test it on my nokia lumia 820 which is windows phone 8 device. so how to do this. Zune also not detecting my device.

Comment: [7.1 apps work on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13724852/11683), so just fix the issue with your phone not being detected by your PC (which is sort of offtopic here).

Answer (score 3):

There is specific requirement to deploy the .xap file to **WP8** device, you must have Windows 8 PC then you have to install WP8 SDK that's Application Deployment tool allows you to deploy the .XAP file on WP8 device.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Zune is not required for deployment on Windows Phone 8 devices (even for WP7 apps running on WP8).

Visual Studio should detect your device and deploy to it automatically.

EDIT: Visual Studio 2012 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK are required for deploying to WP8 devices.

Comment: not happing getting error; zune must be lunch to deploy on device in visual studio 2010....!

Comment: Deploying to a WP8 device requires Visual Studio 2012 and the WP8 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deploy it using Application Deployment tool, no need to use Zune, it is for Mango