# Windows phone app target version

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've developed a **windows phone app**, with **target version 7.1**, what I want to know is that will this app work in windows phone with **OS 8 or 8.1**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are windows phone 7 apps compatible on windows phone 8 devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724852/are-windows-phone-7-apps-compatible-on-windows-phone-8-devices)

Comment: Will a silverlight app 8.0 work on 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer to your question is **YES**. A app with target version 7.x would run in windows phone 8, but with certain limitations.
But an app with target version 8 will not run in windows phone 7.

For further details look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) page

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously an app targeting version 7 can run in 8 too, as the features available in windows OS 7 are present in windows phone 8 as well but there are many features specific to windows phone 8 or a windows 8 OS which cannot be enjoyed if the app is made in windows 7 OS. Like for an example XNA for windows phone 7 works well in windows phone 8 too but if you go looking at xna for windows phone 8 then you will find that xna comes with new add ons in wp8. Hence I would suggest you to make an updated solution or simultaneously make os specific projects

From the developers POV, I would suggest you to go through this [link](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide) once.

Comment: After upgrading to version 8.0 will it work in OS 7 and 7.1??

Comment: sorry, but the upgraded solution wont :)